# Internet Explorer 7 css color and border conflict

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I have a button with some text inside and its creating white border at the right in IE7:

http://jsbin.com/UBusIHa/1

```
<div class="btn">text</div>
```

This border is the color of the text, and it disappears if I remove border-right property, which I need.

How can I get rid of it?

Comment: To remove border right, try css border-right: none; and remove border-right-color property.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any border-color inheritance:

```
* {
    border-color:inherit;
}
```

You have `border-right-width:1px;` and `border-right-style:solid` declarations on that button with CSS (though this could just be IE's ling for parsing the styles).

Removing those in my IE7 Dev Tools removed the border for me, which suggests it is inheriting the color somehow.

You could also specify a `border-right-color` for the `.btn` class.

Comment: If you change color (font) to red you will see this is coming from the color style. If i remove border right, then it goes away, but I need border property.

Comment: @Toniq have you tried specifying a `border-right-color`, or do you have a `* { border-color:inherit; }` declaration anywhere?

Comment: No, I dont have inherit anywhere. I also noticed that if I remove this: border-right-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .1 ); then this while line disappears in ie7, but I cannot remove this as well.

Comment: Border colors shouldn't inherit by default. That `*` rule you have forces the border colors to inherit. But IE7 doesn't support the `inherit` keyword either way.